# Should humidity levels in my attic be the same as outdoors?

Tags: attic, moisture, house

In my attic should the moisture level be the same as outside? I’m in Canada so what should the moisture levels be during the seasons?

Comment: Is this a traditional vented attic, e.g., does it have soffit vents to take air in and roof vents to exhaust air?

Answer (score 3):

Attics are not conditioned spaces. Moisture is not actively controlled as it would be indoors. However, it's important to keep *condensation* from occurring. This is where proper ventilation comes into play.

Be sure you have good full-coverage ventilation in your attic, and that you aren't introducing excess moisture from the habitable space through improperly installed exhaust systems or significant air leaks and you're all set.

Comment: No amount of ventilation will prevent condensation under some common atmospheric conditions - such as the dank, saturated winter air found in the Pacific Northwes that will condense on all non-heated surfaces no matter what.

Comment: I'm not sure how that changes anything here. It's not like you're going to install a dehumidifier up there.

Comment: Yep - the OP should make sure that there aren't any active sources of humidity that are getting into that unconditioned attic space.  Make sure any bathroom/kitchen/dryer vents are properly routed to the outside and aren't dumping humid air into that unconditioned space.